# New-PSDrive : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Credential'. userName

Tags: powershell

I get the Cannot process credentials without error, even when I use the Get-Credential cmdlet to enter user/password directly, or the NetworkCredital like below.  Here's my method - 1st I store the encrypted password in a separate run in a vault file.  Then run this code to perform a network share map:

```
$vault = 'C:\pwd.txt'

# retrieve the password.
$securestring = convertto-securestring -string (get-content $vault)
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($securestring)
$passwsord = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)

$mycreds = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("$User", "$passwsord"); 

New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root “\\server\share” -Credential $mycreds -Persist
```

Here is the error -
-Persist
New-PSDrive : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Credential'. userName
At line:18 char:119

- ... s” -Credential $mycreds -Persist
- ```
                 ~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-PSDrive], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

Comment: You'll want to use a pscredential vs a network credential.

Comment: You also spelled password wrong.